# Get actual location rather than mocked location

Tags: java, android, gps

Android has a option in developer options to mock location. If my understanding is correct, if you set this location, the applications will start getting this location rather then the actual location?

If that is the case, how can we get the actual location regardless of what is set in this option?

If this is not the case, when is the mock location actually used (only in emulators?)?

Comment: You can filter the mock locations using below method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html#isFromMockProvider() and then display some sort of message to user to stop the fake location provider.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge, we cant't get actual location if we are using MOKE location,

**Use of Moke location**

Suppose you are developing a application in Australia region, and you want to test your application in USA environment (Location only) without going there, In that case we are using Moke location.

I think location coming from android frameworks library , and these apis written is such a way, if you was set Moke location, then api will give priority to moke location only. So if you want to use actual location you need to stop moke loaction.

You can write your own api which will directly talk to gps, then might be you will do it, But its major project itself

**EDIT**

You can check MockSetting option is on or off

```
/**
 *returns true if mock location enabled, false if not enabled.
**/
public static boolean isMockLocationStatus(Context context) {
  if (Settings.Secure.getString(context.getContentResolver(),
                                Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0"))
     return false;
  else
     return true;
 }
```

Comment: I can stop mocking location but if my application relies on correct locations, the user can still fake it easily. What is the approch if you want to provide security based on location?